# MYSQL трудности с запросом в запросе или черт знает что

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, запрос-в-запросе

Имею таблицу в MYSQL: 
`

```
CREATE TABLE events (
         uid INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
         time_event DATETIME,
         id_user INT(11),
         direct INT(1),
         PRIMARY KEY (uid)
    )
```

Где 
time_event - дата и время события, 
direct - направление события (вход(4)/выход(5)),
ну и ид_узер - человек.

Задача встала вывести табель первого входа и последнего выхода и отработанное время, с ней на удивление справился быстро, но единственное не смог учесть направления, запросом ниже я получаю первое и последнее событие дня по узеру и отработанное время:

```
SELECT id_user as 'ID', 
        DATE(time_event) as 'Дата',
        TIME(min(time_event)) as 'Вход', 
        TIME(max(time_event)) as 'Выход', 
        SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(max(time_event))-TIME_TO_SEC(min(time_event))) as 'Раб время'
FROM events
WHERE DATE(time_event) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY id_user, DATE(time_event) 
ORDER BY id_user ASC,
        DATE(time_event) ASC


  ID |   Дата   |  Вход  | Выход  | Раб вр
68327|2019-01-18|13:26:37|17:27:14|04:00:37
68327|2019-01-19|13:26:37|17:27:14|04:00:37
68327|2019-01-20|13:26:37|17:27:14|04:00:37
68327|2019-01-21|13:26:37|17:27:14|04:00:37
```

Уважаемые спецы, голову сломал уже, как сделать запрос, чтобы по сотруднику за месяц получить сумму всех "Раб вр"?

Помогите пожалуйста, кто чем сможет!

Какой запрос в запросе надо сделать, чтобы рассчитать сначала по условию группы (сотрудник+дата) разницу макс и мин значений времени, а потом это все просуммировать за месяц (или какой либо выбранный период)?

Хочу в итоге получить что-то вроде:

```
  ID | MONTH|SUMTIME
68327|   1  |16:02:**
```

PS не судите строго, только-только начал погружаться в дебри SQL

Comment: `TIME(min(CASE WHEN direct=4 THEN time_event END)) as 'Вход'`. И по аналогии с выходом.

Comment: Что бы получить сумму, представьте, что этот запрос таблица. И сделайте выборку из нее с группировкой по сотруднику и месяцу. Т.е. `select id, ..., sum(work_time) from ( ваш-текущий-запрос) x group by id, month(date) ...` только внутри конечно разницу просто в секундах получите, что бы суммировать проще было